# ... and suddenly, bluetooth stopped working: No default controller available

Tags: bluetooth, 19.04, intel-nuc

I have looked at previous similar questions, but still I can't make it work.

I have tried with the previous kernel (which I didn't upgrade recently btw).

In my Intel NUC8 bios the bluetooth is enabled.

But if I try to connect to my bluetooth speaker I only see this:

```
➜  ~ bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]# connect 00:22:37:54:51:53
No default controller available
```

I am not sure this could help, but I have noticed that this command

```
➜  ~ dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[    3.801286] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    3.801773] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.801777] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.801779] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.801784] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.500700] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    4.500702] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    4.500705] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    5.858216] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0xfc05 tx timeout
[    5.858217] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version information failed (-110)
```

returns a `Reading Intel version information failed (-110)`

Any idea?

Comment: I've solved this by turning the power off and on again. Just shutting the pc down was not enough, though... I had to phisically detach it from the power line.
I took the suggestion from here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1824703

Comment: To add more strangeness to this - I simply disconnected my laptop charger, reloaded the kernel module and it started working.

Comment: I just needed to shut down my laptop, wait ~10 seconds, then turn it back on again. Thank you for the tips.

Comment: Crazy! Powering this offer, without the cable, has actually worked.

Answer (score 2):

I also resolved this by powering down my laptop, as mentioned by the question's author [in a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1150738/and-suddenly-bluetooth-stopped-working-no-default-controller-available#comment1912841_1150738).

Simply restarting did not resolve the issue. To be completely paranoid, I also unplugged the machine from the power supply before powering it back on. Bluetooth magically re-appeared.